# Problems trying to use Project Loom/Virtual Threads with OpenJDK 19-loom JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, process, project-loom

I'm trying to test the virtual threads reference loom project in Java and I'm using the following JDK 19-loom version:

[image]

```
  package com;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

    public class a {
    
    
        public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
            Runnable printThread = () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    
            ThreadFactory virtualThreadFactory = Thread.builder().virtual().factory();
            ThreadFactory kernelThreadFactory = Thread.builder().factory();
    
            Thread virtualThread = virtualThreadFactory.newThread(printThread);
            Thread kernelThread = kernelThreadFactory.newThread(printThread);
    
            virtualThread.start();
            kernelThread.start();
    
        }
    }
```

And I have the following IntelliJ configuration:

[image]

But I am having the following error:

[image]

And it seems that the builder of the thread is not identified

[image]

**I would like to know what else do I need?**

Comment: Have you tried compiling this outside of IntelliJ? If IntelliJ uses the --release flag with language level 11 you will only get library symbols from 11. AFAIK 19 doesn't work with IntelliJ currently though (maybe the EA version supports it...).

Answer (score 6):

You are using an outdated example.

With the current state of Loom, your example has to look like

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable printThread = () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

    ThreadFactory virtualThreadFactory = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();
    ThreadFactory kernelThreadFactory = Thread.ofPlatform().factory();

    Thread virtualThread = virtualThreadFactory.newThread(printThread);
    Thread kernelThread = kernelThreadFactory.newThread(printThread);

    virtualThread.start();
    kernelThread.start();

    virtualThread.join();
    kernelThread.join();
}
```

but you can also use the simplified

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable printThread = () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

    Thread virtualThread = Thread.startVirtualThread(printThread);
    Thread kernelThread = Thread.ofPlatform().start(printThread);

    virtualThread.join();
    kernelThread.join();
}
```

Keep in mind that this is work in progress and documents can become outdated quite fast.